# CAML query filter with period (.) not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query

I am using SPQuery object and SharePoint list item having period inside its title field value. I tried many ways but no luck. Is it correct that CAML query filter not works with Period? OR I made any mistake in query. I also tried using U2U Caml Query builder and it also not showing result. Is there any work around.
E.g.

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name='Title' />
     <Value Type='Text'>Test.t</Value>
  </Eq></Where>
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the value in a `<![CDATA[]]>` tag, like `<![CDATA[Test.t]]>`?

Comment: Yes I tried with CDATA but not wokring.

Comment: Sorry Robert. It even does not need to use CDATA with period. It's working. I am executing query against Document Library and the list item is inside folder. I forgot to include "Scope=\"Recursive\"". My mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tested this on SP2013 and it works with periods without problems, so it must be something else.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Sorry. It's working. I am executing query against Document Library and the list item is inside folder. I forgot to include "Scope=\"Recursive\"". My mistake.

Comment: @dhavalkariya you should really post your own answer stating what you did wrong and then mark that as the answer

Comment: Okay. I thought this answer states correct too. I got your point. Thanks for pointing out this.